# Best way to merge multiple PDF's into one, downloaded from Azure Blob Storage using Python?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, pypdf, bytesio

Am trying to download multiple PDF files from Azure and combine them (using PyPDF2 library) all into one PDF for re-upload into azure.

Am currently getting an error of `PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Unsupported PNG filter 4` on line `pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(output)`.

```
    consolidated_pdf = review_level_str.title() + '.pdf'
    merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
    
    for each_file in filename_lst:
        blob_client = blob_service.get_blob_client(container=f'{flask_env}-downloads', blob=each_file)
        blob_object = blob_client.download_blob()

        bytes_file = blob_object.readall()
        output = io.BytesIO()
        output.write(bytes_file)
        pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(output)
        merger.append(pdf)

    blob_client_pdf = blob_service.get_blob_client(container=f'{flask_env}-downloads', blob=consolidated_pdf)
    blob_client_pdf.upload_blob(pdf.getvalue())
```

Comment: How'S going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: I was able to utilize the example code before and it worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that my solution is helpful. Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept it as an answer, it will help others and close this question : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient 
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import shutil,os


pdf_list = ['test1.pdf','test2.pdf']
container = 'pdf'
storage_conn_str = ''

tempPath = 'd:/home/temp2/'
os.mkdir(tempPath)

mergedObject = PdfFileMerger()
ContainerClient = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(storage_conn_str,container)

for pdf in pdf_list:
    localPdfPath = tempPath + pdf
    with open(localPdfPath, "wb") as download_file:
        download_file.write(ContainerClient.download_blob(pdf).readall())
    mergedObject.append(localPdfPath)

mergedPDFPath = tempPath + 'merged.pdf'
mergedObject.write(mergedPDFPath)
mergedObject.close()

with open(mergedPDFPath, "rb") as stream:
    ContainerClient.upload_blob('merged.pdf',stream, overwrite=True)

#remove all temp files after upload.
shutil.rmtree(tempPath)
```

Result:
[image]

Check the `merged.pdf`:

[image]

[image]

Let me know if you have any more questions.